# Google Custom search migrate from API 1 to API v 2.0

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Using Google Custom search API v1, Image search, after every image results can be added a button using "setOnKeepCallback"

e.g:

```
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('id',customSearchOptions)
var imageSearcher = customSearchControl.getImageSearcher();
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('searchcontrol');
    customSearchControl.setOnKeepCallback(this, customMethod, "Button Title");
```

In documentation for API v2.0 I don't find anything like this, some ideas ?

Can't find migration table how to implement old functionality, any source will be welcome

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the results?

Comment: @CodyG. because results are in small size to https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:some_hash, but i need original size of images

Comment: Oh sorry I meant in API v2 it returns JSON, so you have to fetch the image with that result, correct? So why don't you fetch the image (using AJAX) and then use a callback on that ? (Sorry I don't know google-custom-search at all, so I'm merely trying to get you to expand your question)

Comment: @CodyG. using url https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1 can get json, this is JSON/ATOM API, but not custom search API v 2.0